# MySql query: DELETE FROM. Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
foreach ($checkArray as $key => $value) {

    $deleteUserStmt=$user_home->runQuery("DELETE FROM users WHERE userID = '".$key."' " AND " '".$value."'=1");

$deleteUserStmt->execute();
}
```

Am getting error:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

$checkArray $key is userID and value is true  or false. RunQuery method  working with other queries.

So I think I have problem with query syntax?

Comment: echo it and see; like $del = "DELETE FROM ....."; echo $del;

Comment: Just from syntax highlighting `$key."' " AND "` should tell you that is off... presuming you've already taken care of SQL injections with this code.

Comment: why would someone put single quotes for columns. shouldn't be `column_name` with a tilda

Comment: backticks rather than tilda

Comment: sorry raider. not tilda, tilda is ~ and backticks is `

Comment: @Plum good point but wrong context a tilde is `~` OP should use backticks `\``

Answer (score 0):

Query should be like this, dont put single quotes for the column names: 

`"DELETE FROM users WHERE userID = '$key' AND $value='1'"`